# How do I set a timeout for writing to a slow filesystem in PHP?

Tags: php, php-5.6

**I want to write to a file from PHP, and set a timeout for that operation to 5 seconds.**

I am writing a PHP script to check if a mounted NFS server is available for writing. I need an alert if it is unavailable. If the NFS server is disconnected, then different ways of trying to write to it will fail immediately, and I can then send an alert easily. No problem so far.

But when it is slow (perhaps due to bandwidth congestion or server load) a simple approach such as `file_put_contents()` can take several minutes, as it does not timeout, and eventually succeeds.

I have tried various `combinations of file_get_contents()`, `fwrite()`, `stream_set_timeout()`, `ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 5)` but with no success.

**Is it possible to set a timeout for writing to a file? If so, how?**

---

Here's a sample of what I have tried:

```
<?php

$f = '/path/to/file';
$test = 'some large string';

$fp = fopen($f , 'w', false, $ctx);

if (!$fp) {
    echo "Unable to open\n";
} else {

    stream_set_timeout($fp, 0, 1000);
    fwrite($fp, $text);

    $info = stream_get_meta_data($fp);
    print_r($info);
    fclose($fp);

    if ($info['timed_out']) {
        echo 'Connection timed out!';
    }
}

/*
Outputs:
Array
(
    [timed_out] =>
    [blocked] => 1
    [eof] =>
    [wrapper_type] => plainfile
    [stream_type] => STDIO
    [mode] => w
    [unread_bytes] => 0
    [seekable] => 1
    [uri] => /path/to/file
)
*/
```

Comment: so are you trying to force a timeout?

Comment: **Danger** You've tagged this [tag:php-5.6]  but that version of PHP has been **unsupported** since last year. Upgrade to [a supported version](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php).

Comment: @treyBake I would like to force a timeout to test my code. But when for example I write 3GB of data and it takes 1.4 seconds, that means that my 1 second timeout has failed.

Comment: @Quentin Thank you, an upgrade plan is in place.

Comment: Maybe writing the data using small chunks in a loop and then keeping track of the total time and abort if it takes too long?

Comment: @MartinWickman My script usually takes <0.1s to write 10M. On some runs it took ~20 minutes. I suspect that there can be something blocking the write from completing, and that it would also block if I try to write only a single byte. I'm trying to monitor the write performance to detect when it is slower than normal, and I cannot reproduce the issue using small chunks without breaking the NFS server. So a timeout mechanism for writing any number of bytes is the ideal solution.

Comment: Try `stream_set_blocking($fp, FALSE );` after the timeout, before the write. You would need to compare the result of fwrite to the size of what you attempted to write. If less, it was not able to write the entire thing in the time allotted.

Comment: (updating [code](https://3v4l.org/fiCFU) to check if `time()` is greater than `$maxExec`) - will rm my prev. link in < 5mins

Comment: I would say `pcntl_alarm()` is the only way in case NFS client cannot talk to the server with mounted filesystem.